# Detect screen resolution independently of page zoom level and Windows scale settings

Tags: javascript

I need to detect screen resolution. The problem is, if scale setting in Windows 10 is not 100%, it affects `screen.width` / `screen.height` values.

I could use `pixelDeviceRatio` for correct them, but here is another problem: if the page is zoomed, it also affects `pixelDeviceRatio`.

For example, I have Windows scale setting is 150%, and page zoom is 67%. My screen resolution is 1920x1080. In this case, `screen.width` is 1280, and `pixelDeviceRatio` is 1.0 (because Windows scale and page zoom level compensate each other). How can I detect the real screen resolution?

Upd.: I'm working on HTML5 game. I need to resize it to actual screen resolution when going to fullscreen mode.

Upd. 2: I have `<canvas>` element and call its `requestFullscreen` method to switch into fullscreen mode. Then I have to set width and height of the canvas. If I set it, for example, less than actual screen resolution (1280 instead of 1920), empty margins around the canvas appears.

Comment: why do you want to detect the screen resolution? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @ADyson, answered above

Comment: Your update doesn't make it clear **why** you "need to resize it to actual screen resolution". Why can't you just resize it to the *reported* size? Moreover in such a complex case as two interpolation algorithms working concurrently. What makes you think that rendering *exact screen size x some ratio x some other ratio* would make any good? There are big chances that you end up with mashed pixels anyway. Plus, if your users have such settings, they might have good reasons, and you may deserve them trying to against these settings.

Comment: @Kaiido I have tried to explain in the last update (sorry for my English)

Comment: I don't know why pepople give negative if they don't understand the issue.... This question is valid and giving +1 vote..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), OP doesn't want the *screen* resolution, but the one of the document.

---

***Note for future readers.***
There are chances that if you also are trying to get the actual screen resolution, you are yourself in some kind of an XY problem.

If what you want is sharp pixels, getting the actual screen resolution won't help you much.

Taking OP's example of a browser zoom of 75% itself scaled by the OS zoom at 150%, we get for a single white pixel,

- 1 white pixel x 0.75 => impossible to render. => anti-aliasing with surrounding pixels. So if we say that surrounding pixels were black, then we've now got a grayish pixel.

And this was only at the browser level... We still have to pass the OS zoom algorithm.

- 1 grayish pixel x 1.5 => impossible to render => anti-aliasing with surrounding pixels. And yet a new pixel, even farther from our original white.

---

**The best we can do here is to set our canvas bitmap's size to the one reported by the browser.** This way, only the OS zoom would kick in.

*Note:* You may want to try to detect high density screens a.k.a *retina®*, which are actually able to render pixels at sub-px level, in this case, you might try using *window.devicePixelRatio* as a general scaling factor, but remember to round it, since a floating scale would mean more antialiasing (no high density screen will ever use 2.3 pixels to render one px).

So to detect this document size, is an easy task, with multiple different ways of doing:

If you deal with hard-coded sizes in windowed mode, you can simply check for `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` when entering fullScreen:

<sub>Unfortunately, StackSnippets® iframe do not allow fullscreen mode...</sub>

```
// listen for the resize event
window.onresize = function() {
  // if we are in fullscreen mode
  if (document.fullscreenElement === canvas) {
    // simply size our canvas to the reported innerWidth/innerHeight.
    W = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    H = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
  draw();
}
// in the fulscreenchange event
document.onfullscreenchange = function() {
    // if we are exiting the fullscreen mode
    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
      // set  back to hard-coded values
      W = canvas.width = 500
      H = canvas.height = 200;
    }
    draw();
  }
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rmsj29g/).

If you want something more dynamic, you could also make use of CSS to let you know the actual size. Indeed, you can resize your canvas through CSS, as long as you remember to set its bitmap's size to the displayed size.

```js
// listen only for the resize event
window.onresize = function() {
  // set the canvas size to its own rendered size
  W = canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  H = canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
  draw();
}
```

```css
/* target only when in fullscreen mode */
canvas::fullscreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
/* windowed mode */
canvas {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t84ujeq7/).

Comment: I totally forgot about `vw`/`vh` and `:fullscreen` in CSS. Thank you very much, it's very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var width = screen.width
var height = screen.height
width = width*window.devicePixelRatio;
height = height*window.devicePixelRatio;

alert("width : "+width);
alert("height : "+height);
```

Comment: Thank you.
Unfortunately, if in Windows the scale setting is set not to 100%, `devicePixelRatio` not reflects page zoom level.

Comment: what are trying to do ? detect screen resolution or the page zoom level.

Comment: I'm trying to detect screen resolution. But if I know the page zoom level, I can calculate the resolution too.




Due to the fact that Windows scale setting and Page zoom level both affects `devicePixelRatio` value, but only Windows scale setting affects `screen.width` value, I can find it, if I know the page zoom level.

Comment: I think the answer i gave gives you the screen width and the screen height independently of the screen zoom

Comment: Yes it is, but not independently of screen scale settings in Windows 10.

Comment: You're right...
But i don't think what you are trying to do is possible using javascript...
That's my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no JavaScript api to detect os scale factor.